# Hard Drive noted as 'Failing' in Mac OS X and Other installations

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, laptop, windows-8.1

Recently I tried to dual boot OpenBSD and Windows 8.1. Unfortunately for me, I was inexperienced in fdisk and accidentally formatted my hard drive :( I tried to install Windows again but it refused because 'drive 0 partition 2 might fail soon.' I am trying to install Mac OS X instead but this again, refuses to install because 'TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050 has a hardware problem that can't be repaired.' Do I have to completely order a new drive? I am positive that this can be fixed and ordering a new hard drive would be a last resort. 
Please help! :(

--EDIT--

I forgot to include Disk Utility stats at the installation. Apparently the S.M.A.R.T. status is 'failing'

Comment: Here is the link to the other question I have posted in the Microsoft Community: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/windows-8-install-error-0x8007045d-ive-had-it-with/5cc5bceb-7f77-405a-9a8f-ef03545832e7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SMART status indicates that the drive is failing, then yes, you're looking at buying a new hard drive.

The fact that it failed while you were trying to set up a dual-boot configuration is just a coincidence.  The drive was set to die on you regardless.